# Why crontab choose to execute one of the command over other?

Tags: pi-2, script, cron, real-time

So, basically I am using wiringPI library and its sample code for ds1302 chip. It works great by the way - writing and reading to and from ds1302 chip is a breeze. I can initiate PI's date and time update with ds1302 date and time and vice versa. I want to automate this process for boot-time and periodic update of ds1302 chip with PI's date and time. I got the boot-time PI's date and time update from ds1302 date and time by calling a script at boot.

For periodic update of ds1302 date time from PI's date time, I am using `sudo crontab -e` The script itself is working as expected but not updating my ds1302 chip's date time. In the crontab, I have the following.

```
* * * * * date>>/home/pi/script/cron.txt
* * * * * sudo ./home/pi/script/ds1302 -sdsc
```

I know crontab is working, because I do see cron.txt with time stamp for every minute, but the ds1302 chip date time has not updated to the PI's date time. The weird thing is that if I were to execute the command, `sudo ./home/pi/script/ds1302 -sdsc` on the terminal, it WORKS instantly. So, why won't crontab run the command or having difficulty running the command?

Comment: This is a duplicate.  You have been told before to use absolute paths in crontab.  Anything starting with a . is not an absolute path.

Comment: @joan The reason I have . in the beginning is to execute ds1302 program. dot followed by absolute path `/home/pi/script/`.

Comment: You have changed an absolute path to a relative path.  Get rid of the dot.

Comment: @Joan if I do that, how will it know to execute ds1302 program. Do I have to change directory before I run the command?

Comment: You need to look online for a Linux tutorial to explain such things as absolute and relative paths.

Comment: :) I was under the impression that you have to do exactly as you would on the terminal when it comes to executing commands in the crontab. Well, I simply took the DOT out and Viola!!! Thanks, Joan

Comment: You really need to look through a Linux tutorial.  It will cover many similar things to this which will catch you out until you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the dot

`* * * * * sudo /home/pi/script/ds1302 -sdsc`

Comment: You have answered your own question based on @joan comments which is a bit cheeky - you could have at least mentioned here help/comments. Second you have not explained what the removing the dot does and why it worked - this would show you understood the problem and solution not just repeated the advice you were given.